# VBA Range input Value error

Tags: vba, excel, function

I am trying to calculate an output by reading in a Range and then working with it as an array. My formula returns a value error. If write the code as a sub without reading in the array put selecting the Range("") the code works fine. Perhaps you can see m error?

```
Public Function pfsd2A(sdInp As Range, wInp As Range, corInp As Double)

'only for two assets
Dim matrix() As Variant
Dim sd As Variant
Dim w As Variant
Dim cor As Double 'should be a matrix for more than 2 assets!!
Dim out As Variant

sd = sdInp.Value
w = sdInp.Value
cor = corInp
assetnum = UBound(sd)

ReDim matrix(1 To assetnum, 1 To assetnum)

Debug.Print sd(1, 1)

For j = 1 To assetnum
    For i = 1 To assetnum
        matrix(i, j) = w(j, 1) ^ 2 * sd(j, 1) ^ 2 + w(i, 1) ^ 2 * sd(i, 1) ^ 2 + 2 * w(i, 1) * w(j, 1) * sd(i, 1) * sd(j, 1) * cor
        Cells(i, j) = matrix(i, j)
    Next i
Next j

VarPf = Application.WorksheetFunction.MMult(Application.WorksheetFunction.MMult(Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(w), matrix), w)

pfsd2A = Sqr(VarPf(1))

End Function
```

Comment: How are you calling this function?

Comment: My guess is you are trying to call this function from the worksheet: `Cells(i, j) = matrix(i, j)` is what is causing the error.  A function called by the worksheet cannot effect the value of any other cell but the one that calls the function.  Take that line out and you get your answer in the cell that called the function.